# Is there a way to use weights in glmmLasso in R?

Tags: r, lasso, glmm, weights

I would like to use weights in a model that I'm fitting with the `glmmLasso` package, but it looks like there isn't an option for it. I've previously fit models with the `glm()` and `glmer()` functions, which both have a `weights =` option. However, it looks like `glmmLasso` doesn't have such an option, and the older version (`glmmlasso` with a lowercase L) which did have a weights option is unfortunately now defunct. Alternatively, if there's a way to use LASSO on `glmer()` that would work too.

In summation: I'd like to fit a GLMM in R that uses both sampling weights and LASSO variable selection. Is there a way to do this? I'm open to any/all solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Supplying a vector, $w$ to the `weights` argument in `glm` returns the same result as first scaling both the response variable and design matrix by $\sqrt{w}$ and fitting without the `weights` argument. e.g.

```
set.seed(1234)
toy_data <- data.frame(x = 1:20, y = 1:20 + rnorm(20), w = runif(20, 5, 25))
m1 <- lm(y ~ x, weights = w, data = toy_data)
dmat <- matrix(c(rep(1, 20), toy_data$x), ncol = 2) #design matrix
dmat_w <- dmat * sqrt(toy_data$w)
y_w <- toy_data$y * sqrt(toy_data$w)
m2 <- lm(y_w ~ 0 + dmat_w)
summary(m1)
summary(m2)
```

You may be able to do the same thing with `glmmLasso`